# как узнать есть ли объект в массиве

Tags: javascript

есть массив объектов

```
users = [
    {name: 'Андрей', login: 'meow', password: 'qwerty123'},
    {name:'Матвей',login:'Marro',password:'12345678'},
    {name:'Егор',login:'cloudy',password:'qawsed123'}
];
```

как узнать есть ли в нем объект со свойством `login: Marro`

Comment: Таких вопросов уже вагон и маленькая тележка.

Comment: @doox911, предложи дубликат, я закрою

Comment: @Grundy, я имел в виду — поиск ключа.

Comment: `users.filter(function(u){ return u.login == 'Marro'}).length > 0`

Comment: @doox911, и я про то же, если таких вопросов вагон - дай ссылку на один, я закрою как дубликат.

Comment: @Grundy https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/806243/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5-php Например.

Comment: @doox911, вопрос про [tag:javascript] а не про [tag:php] :)

Comment: Прошу прощения. Но вы уже и так закрыли)

Comment: @doox911, ага, но в следующий раз лучше не просто сказать, что таких вопросов много, а дать как раз ссылку на один из таких вопросов, в лучше проголосовать за дубликат.